# How is this working?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I was browsing through one site called BSEINDIA.com (http://www.bseindia.com/stockreach/stockreach.htm?scripcd=532667), i Noticed that on click of Get Quote it seems to fire an Ajax request and get the price of selected equities. I tried to segregate this request and fire it separately, but it doesn't seem to work.

I copied over the code from the HTML of same page (http://www.bseindia.com/stockreach/stockreach.htm?scripcd=532667)
Any pointers why is this not working, is there some sort of Authentication going on , i am not even a member of this site??

following is what i am trying to do

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var oHTTP=getHTTPObject();
var seconds = Math.random().toString(16).substring(2);

if(oHTTP)
{
    oHTTP.open("GET","http://www.bseindia.com/DotNetStockReachs/DetailedStockReach.aspx?GUID="+seconds+"&scripcd=532667",true);
    oHTTP.onreadystatechange=AJAXRes;
    oHTTP.send(null);
}

function AJAXRes()
{
    if(oHTTP.readyState==4)alert(oHTTP.responseText);
}

function getHTTPObject(){var obj;
try{obj=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
catch(e){try{
obj=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
catch(e1){obj=null;}}
if(!obj&& typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined'){
try{obj=new XMLHttpRequest();}
catch(e){obj=false;}}return obj;}



</script>
```

Found out my Answer here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.referer%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is fairly easy. When you send an HTTP request, an header called [`Referrer`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) gets sent with the request. The [`Referrer`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) is basically the URL of the page which initiated the request.

BSEINDIA checks the [`Referrer`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) value to make sure that the request is coming from their site. If it is, it sends the data. If not, it sends its 404 page.

You can easily test that theory by disabling the [`Referrer`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) in your browser. In Firefox, you can do that by typing `about:config` and setting [`network.http.sendRefererHeader`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.sendRefererHeader) to `0`.

If you still want to get the data, you will need to write a script (in PHP or another language) which will make the request with the proper [`Referrer`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) and output the results.

Comment: Maybe worth trying this extension in FF to spoof the referer https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4513

Comment: Perfect, but does that mean that i cant kind of automate this :(

Comment: Thanks, I found out way to do it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.referer%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There might be some form of IP restriction in place for accessing the files / data needed to save themselves from third party scripts accessing their data through their own scripts. Thats what I'd do.

Comment: An AJAX request firing from your browser would have your IP as the origination, wouldn't it?

Comment: Of course it would, but what about the server-side files on the other end?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly [Http Referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer). Make sure you do not break any copyright restriction.